# onclick and get in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button like this

```
<a onclick="japa('myid');">Click Here</a>
```

And javascript like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function japa(r) {
$("#Tamfan").html("");
    $.ajax({
        url     : 'file.php?id=',
        type    : 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success : function(pesan){
                $("#Tamfan").html(pesan);
        },
    });
}
</script>
```

How i add the code of onclick (myid) to code after `?id=` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is done something like this:

```
url     : 'file.php?id=' + r,
```

But you can make use of `data:{}` option of `jQuery.ajax()` method to pass additional data back to server:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function japa(r) {
$("#Tamfan").html("");
    $.ajax({
        url     : 'file.php',
        type    : 'GET',
        data    : { id : r }, //<-----use it here
        dataType: 'html',
        success : function(pesan){
                $("#Tamfan").html(pesan);
        } // <---------remove the comma ',' from here.
    });
}
</script>
```

This data object seems to be more preferred way as this is much better way to organize data strings.

Answer (score 1):

Igf you need to pass the id dynamially, you can pass the object itself and get the id

```
function japa(obj) {
$("#Tamfan").html("");
    $.ajax({
        url     : 'file.php?id='+obj.id,
        type    : 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success : function(pesan){
                $("#Tamfan").html(pesan);
        },
    });
}
```

in the function,

```
<a onclick="japa(this);">Click Here</a>
```

If you are passing the id as string itself, you can use like

```
url     : 'file.php?id='+r,
```

Comment: what is the value of r ?

Comment: `<a onclick="japa('myid');">Click Here</a>` in the brackets ( )

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function japa(r) {
$("#Tamfan").html("");
    $.ajax({
        url     : 'file.php?id=' + r,
        type    : 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success : function(pesan){
                $("#Tamfan").html(pesan);
        },
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mussing the context property:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function japa(r) {
$("#Tamfan").html("");
    $.ajax({
        context : this,
        url     : 'file.php?id='+r,
        type    : 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success : function(pesan){
                $("#Tamfan").html(pesan);
        },
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1st as all previous answers said you need to use

```
url     : 'file.php?id=' + r,
```

but while you use click on anchor *(and if this anchor with href attribute set)* you will need to prevent redirect the page .. so you can use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function japa(e, id) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url     : 'file.php?id=' + id,
        type    : 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success : function(pesan){
                $("#Tamfan").html(pesan);
        },
    });
}
</script>
```

and in html

```
<a href="#" id="Im_ID" onclick="japa(event , this.id);">Click Here</a>
```

and in php file

```
<?php
   if(isset($_GET['id'])){
      echo ('<div>'.$_GET['id'].'</div>');
   }
?>
```

['**Simple demo**'](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/EdJQE/807/)

Comment: although the target element is an anchor still it won't navigate anywhere untill a `href=""` attribute is provided and which seems to be missing isn't it?

Comment: @Jai totally right .. I updated my answer :) to say if it set href attr to anchor .. Thanks :)